# How to make a Boot Disk (700 mb CD)?

Tags: installation, boot

I have several old XP boxes that I would like to convert to Linx.  I have a boot/install disk for both Ubuntu 8.04 and Xubuntu 8.04. I would link to make a boot/install disk on a CD (not a DVD or flash drive) for Ubuntu 12.04.2L.  How do I do this? Please provide the specific steps I would need to follow because everything I have tried to date is not working.  Alternatively, if this is not possible, could I install 8.04 and update to 12.04?

Comment: Note that 8.04 is ancient and no longer supported.

Answer (score 1):

This is a duplicate, please see the link I gave you. You could try the netinstall iso.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD

After the install you would install ubuntu-desktop

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

You would otherwise need to build a custom iso.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization

Answer (score 0):

Simply try to burn iso image of Ubuntu that you have, to a disk using `brasero` application.

Comment: Can you add instructions for doing this?